# Can multithreaded code possible deadlock be avoided this way?

Tags: multithreading, deadlock

We know that multi-threaded code has the bane of possible deadlocks if the threads acquire mutex locks but before it gets a chance to release it, the thread gets suspended by main thread or pre-empted out by Scheduler?

I am a beginner in using pthread library so please bear with me if my below query/proposed solution might be unfeasible or outright wrong.

```
void main()
{
    thread_create(T1,NULL,thr_function,NULL)

    suspend_thread(T1);

    acquire_lock(Lock1);<--- //Now here is a possible deadlock if thread_function acquried Lock1 before main and main suspended T1 before its release
    //Do something further;
}

void *thr_function(void *val)
{
    ///do something;
    acquire_lock(Lock1);
    //do some more things;
    //do some more things;
    release_lock(Lock1);

}
```

In this below pseudo code segment above I have, can't the thread run-time/compiler work together to make sure if a thread which has acquired a mutex lock, is suspended/pre-empted then it executes some 'cleanup code' of releasing all locks it has held before it gets out. The compiler/linker can identify the places inside a thread function which acquire , release lock, then when a thread is suspended between those two places(i.e. after acquire but before release) the execution in the thread function should jump via some kind of '`goto label;`'  inserted by the runtime where at the `label:` the thread would release the lock and then the thread gets blocked or context switch happens. [ I know if a thread acquires more than 1 locks it might get messy to jump across those points to release those locks...]

But basic idea/question is can the thread function not do the necessary releases of acquired locks for mutexes, semaphores before it gets blocked out or goes out of execution state to wait or some other state?

Comment: *Never* use suspend_thread() as a way to implement synchronization.  It is fundamentally unable to do it correctly.

Comment: Having the compiler automagically release the lock in places where the thread was in the middle of doing something on some shared data would defeat the purpose of having a lock in the first place.  The next time the thread executed, it could find that some of the data it was working on had been unexpectedly changed (or even deleted) by another thread, and that would be difficult to handle correctly.

Comment: IME, the deadlock issues you are trying to avoid hardly ever happen and, when they do, the entire app gets siezed up with 0% CPU use - obvious, and so easily fixed.  What you are suggesting is not even 'premature optimization', it's 'premature bug-induction' that will destroy your inter-thread comms before a single line of application-specific code is written.  Please don't do it <g>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. The reason a thread holds a lock is so that it can make data temporarily inconsistent or see a consistent view of that data itself. If some scheme were to automatically release that lock before the thread made the data consistent again, other threads would acquire the lock, see the inconsistent data, and fail. Or when that thread was resumed, it would either not have the lock or have the lock and see inconsistent data itself. This is why you can only reliably suspend a thread with that thread's cooperation.

Consider this logic to add an object to a linked list protected by a mutex:

1. Acquire the lock protecting a linked list.
2. Modify the link's head pointer.
3. Modify the object's next pointer.
4. Release the lock.

Now imagine if something were to suspend the thread between steps 2 and 3. If the lock were released, other threads would see the link's head pointer pointing to an object that had not been linked to the list. And when the thread resumed, it might set the object to the wrong pointer because the list had changed.

The general consensus is that suspending threads is so evil that even a feeling that you might want to suspend a thread suggests an incorrect application design. There is practically no reason a properly-designed application would ever want to suspend a thread. (If you didn't want that thread to continue doing the work it was doing, why did you code it to continue doing that work in the first place?)

By the way, scheduler pre-emption is not a problem. Eventually, the thread will be scheduled again and release the lock. So long as there are other threads that can make forward progress, no harm is done. And if there are no other threads that can make forward progress, the only thing the system can do is schedule the thread that was pre-empted.

Comment: Thanks. I get the point about suspend, but it was just a 'cooked up example' to make a point. But then may be even 'naieve qns' - Why do deadlocks still occur inspite of not using suspend_thread()? They still do occur right?

Comment: @goldenmean: Deadlocks occur due to bugs. The most common is this: Thread A holds lock Z and is waiting for lock Y. Thread B holds locks Y and decides to wait for lock Z. Now threads A and B are waiting for each other ... forever. (The same argument as above shows why you can't fix this case by forcing locks to be released either. You could, however, detect the possible deadlock and return an error when thread B tries to acquire that second lock.)

Comment: The example of object added to list explains it might be ok to have a deadlock,fail predictably than having a random incorrect run time error & unpredictable results if lock is released with data left in inconsistent state.But i still think if there was a another variable which the thread  function can set indicating that it was forced to release a lock which it has but data is not consistent, so if that same thread function code is executed by the next thread, it can check the variable,see the data is inconsistent, so not acqurie the lock itself and exit from there before doing any changes.

Comment: @goldenmean: Sure, if that works well for your particular design, you could write code to do that. I've personally never found a case where that would be useful and really can't imagine one. But if you have one, then do it that way. (I have no idea what would happen when you resume the thread though. How would that work?)

Comment: I'm with @DavidSchwartz on this one.  The risks of dubious-at-best schemes like the OP one are greater than the risk of deadlock.  I've never found deadlock to much of a problem anyway.  On the odd occasion that I've induced it by bad design/coding, the result was immediately obvious - the whole app seized up with 0% CPU use - and so was easily fixed.  I'd much rather have that than once-every-2-weeks support calls from customers with corrupted data due to some irreproducible concurrency issue.

Answer (score 0):

One way to avoid this kind of deadlocks is to have a global, mutexed variable `should_stop_thread` which eventually gets set to `true` by the master thread.

The child thread checks the variable regularly and terminates in a controlled manner if it is `true`. "Controlled" in this sense means that all data (pointers) are valid (again) and mutex locks are released.

Comment: Could you elaborate more. What is 'terminates in a controlled manner'?

Comment: @goldenmean: with "controlled" I mean releasing any mutex locks and assuring that all data is valid (again).

Comment: I wouldn't do this either.  Wots with all the panic/FUD about deadlocks?  I've never had a deadlock issue that was not immediately obvious and easily fixable.  I refuse to believe that I'm just lucky - never happens with the horses/dogs/lottery :(

Comment: @Martin: Whether you get a deadlock or another unwanted situation once in a million times (seemingly never) or once every 100 times (== all time time) also depends on whether you run on 2 Cpu's or 20000.

Comment: @steffen - true.  I don't get deadlocks and I don't get support calls about deadlocks - that's good enough for me! <g>  I don't have any GPU array or massively-parallel supercomputer to test my code on, so I'll take what I have for now:)

Comment: @MartinJames: That's totally fine. Sometimes the possibility of a deadlock is rather academic...